# Getting the record count from an update statement

Tags: oracle, dataset, loadrunner

I have a test script running in Microfocus Loadrunner. The script sends a request to update 100 records. However, due to duplicates, missing data etc, we regularly find <100 records are updated. This is intended behaviour.

When I run the query in SQL Developer or similar, I get '97 row(s) affected'. I can then log this number to find how many records I've updated. But the command in Loadrunner that does the query (lr_db_executeSQLStatement) does not return this value, instead it just returns 'no dataset'. It can only return information from a select statement.

Is there a way of 'wrapping' the update statement in a select statement that would return the number of records affected? In psuedo code, something like this;

```
select affectedrows from dual where query = (update table set x=y where z)
```

Answer (score 0):

After each DML statement you can access cursor variable `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, for example

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' rows affected' );
```

Note, The value of the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` attribute refers to the most recently executed SQL statement from PL/SQL. You should run such statement directly after your DML.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, from SQL Developer I get 'Error report - Unknown Command', from Loadrunner I get 'ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement'.

Comment: Enclose it by `begin ... end;` or try `exec DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' rows affected' );`

Comment: Yep, the answer below pushed me towards that. It does now run, but I still don't get a dataset. As it's a dbms_output rather than the response of a select statement, it just disappears into oblivion. Can I get to SQL%ROWCOUNT in the form of a select statement?

Comment: I think SQL%ROWCOUNT is available only inside PL/SQL

Comment: OK, so is there a way of presenting the output of the PL/SQL block as a dataset? I did see dbms_sql.return_result, but that doesn't work and I don't know what it actually does.

Comment: Package DBMS_SQL is used to run **very** dynamic SQL statements - not for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function for it as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_MY_TABLE(Y IN <DATATYPE>, Z IN <DATATYPE>)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE <TABLE> SET X = ' || Y || ' WHERE <SOME_COL> = ' || Z;
RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END;
/

-- then call the function to update the desired value
-- using desired where condition
-- Function will return the number of rows affected

num_rows_affected := UPDATE_MY_TABLE(<update value>,<update condition value>);
```

I have created a small demo of the same.

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63448aa1f2f19c94748c94f055e47bed)

Hope, It will solve your problem.

Cheers!!